# Devops Pipeline Serialization Issue

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Error I am trying to solve in job #2 (AKA powershell script #2) of my build that accepts a variable from job #1:
[image]

I have a build pipeline in ADO defined by my yaml file:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - 'master'
  paths:
    include:
    - dev/*

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: Build
  pool:
    name: 'DBDevOps_Stage'
  steps:
    - checkout: self

    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "The directory for the checked out code is: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
        git log $(Build.SourceVersion)..HEAD --oneline
      displayName: 'Print Sources Directory'

    - powershell: |
        . "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\prevalidation.ps1" -SecretVariable $(CDCUSERSECRET) -envType $(envType) -KafkaSecret $(KAFKASECRET) -KafkaKey $(KAFKAKEY)
      name: setVariableStep
      displayName: 'Run Prevalidation Script'
      env:
        CDCUSERSECRET: $(CDCUserSecret) # This maps the Azure DevOps variable to an environment variable
        ENV: $(envType)
        KAFKASECRET: $(kafkasecret)
        KAFKAKEY: $(kafkakey)
      continueOnError: false
- job: Release
  dependsOn: Build
  variables:
    theVariable: $[ dependencies.Build.outputs['setVariableStep.myVariable'] ]
  pool:
    name: 'DBDevOps_Stage'
  steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host $(theVariable)
    - powershell: |
        . "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Release.ps1" -myVariable $(theVariable)
      displayName: 'Release Script'
```

In my prevalidation.ps1 file, I am converting a PSObject[] into a JSON string to prevent awkward serialization:

```
$ComplexObjectArraylist = ($ComplexObjectArraylist | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5).ToString()
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable;isOutput=true;]$ComplexObjectArraylist"
```

I noticed in the console that when the variable outputs, it is leaving off the initial "[", which causes a failure in my Release.ps1 as it tries to call ConvertFrom-Json on an invalid object. However, if I simply write-host the variable in my prevalidation.ps1 file, the output is proper and the leading bracket is not missing from the output.

I have done quite a lot of troubleshooting, but the most interesting thing I did was to add a Powershell step that simply outputted the variable, but instead of outputting the entire string/json object with the leading "[" missing, it literally just printed out ONLY the "[" itself:

[image]

Comment: In the serialization step, change `$ComplexObjectArraylist | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5` to `$ComplexObjectArraylist | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 -Compress` (to avoid multi-line output)

Comment: That "fixed" the output of the basic powershell write-host script by including the full string instead of just the first "[". However, when it made it to the actual Release.ps1 where I immediately run ConvertFrom-Json, it prompts a bunch of syntax errors: Unexpected token ':"alpha"' in expression or statement. & Missing argument in parameter list.
 etc. When I run the same setup locally in Azure Data Studio, it properly converts it back no problem.

Edit: It looks like -Compress removes quotations

Comment: Make sure you place the variable macro inside quotation marks so you get a valid string literal in the resulting PowerShell script: `$(theVariable)` -> `'$(theVariable)'`

Comment: The combination of -Compress and enclosing the variable in '' worked like a charm! I'm still not sure I fully comprehend why -Compress is necessary, but if you want to post your comment as an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your variable output contains unescaped newlines, and AzDO automatically interprets those as "end of input".

To work around this, in the serialization step, change `$ComplexObjectArraylist | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5` to `$ComplexObjectArraylist | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 -Compress`.

This will cause `ConvertTo-Json` to output the whole document without line breaks or other trivial whitespace.

Since AzDO variable macros are expanded in source code, make sure you quote the expanded value once you consume it:

```
$jsonString = '$(theVariable)'
```

... so that the resulting source code is `$jsonString = '{"abc":"def",...}'` instead of `$jsonString = {"abc":"def",...}` (which isn't valid PowerShell)